# ML Kit for Cyrillic

Tags: ios, flutter, ocr, google-cloud-vision

guys! I built a Flutter app on Android using Firebase ML Vision, but I had to change to Google ML Kit for my iOS build since Firebase ML Vision was discontinued. I was able to run the app, but google_ml_kit 0.7.3 is not able to recognize Cyrillic letters.

Is it possible to use Cloud Recognition with Flutter on iOS to identify Cyrillic letters? If not, is there any other solution?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There isn’t a way on cloud recognition, if I remember rightly the only non Latin it supports is Mandarin, Arabic and Japanese-  but try one of these plugins https://github.com/rxlabz/speech_recognition

Pubspec.yaml is the most effective from previous personal use